# Solve : $p^2+ 2py \cot(x) = y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve : $p^2+ 2py \cot(x) = y^2$ where p = dy/dx

My approach to the question :
I used the quadratic formula to get $$y = p \cot(x) \pm p \csc(x) $$ which can be reduced to $y = -P(v \pm 1)$ where $v = \cos(x)$ and $P = \dfrac{dy}{dv}$. Now this can be solved using Clairaut's equation and I am getting $$y = -c(\cos(x) \pm 1) $$ But the solution given is $y(1 \pm \cos(x)) = c$.

Could you point out my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I believe, OP should clearly say what is $p$.

Answer (score 2):

You set $y(x)=u(\cos x)$ with $p(x)=y'(x)=-\sin x\,u'(\cos x)$. Inserting into the equation gives
$$
(1-v^2)u'(v)^2-2vu(v)u'(v)=u(v)^2
\\
u'(v)^2=(u(v)+vu'(v))^2\iff u'(v)=\pm(vu(v))'
$$
This indeed integrates to
$$
u(v)(1\mp v)=c.
$$

---

You want to interpret
$$
vu'(v)+ u(v)=\pm u'(v)
$$
as Clairaut equation. This has the wrong sign on the left side, as one would need $u=u'v+f(u')\iff vu'(v)-u(v)=-f(u'(v))$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'^2+ 2y'y \cot(x) = y^2$$
$$\left ( \dfrac {y'}{y}\right)^2+ 2\left ( \dfrac {y'}{y}\right) \cot(x) = 1$$
$$\left ( \dfrac {y'}{y}+\cot x\right )^2 =1+ \cot^2 x$$
$$ \dfrac {y'}{y}+\cot x =\pm \dfrac {1}{\sin x}$$
$$ (\ln y )'+\cot x =\pm \dfrac {1}{\sin x}$$
Integrate.